# why same character have different byte representations and how to convert

Tags: bash, macos, unicode, encoding, utf-8

```
$ printf ボ | hexdump 
0000000 e3 83 9c                                       
0000003
$ printf ボ | hexdump 
0000000 e3 83 9b e3 82 99                              
0000006
```

^ is output under Mac OS terminal.

The one with 6 bytes is extracted from filename(I saw some say mac filename encoding issue, not so sure about it)

The other is extracted from a xml file content(XML 1.0 document text, UTF-8 Unicode text).

And I was trying to grep the filename from the xml file and I guess ^ is the reason causing it.

I tried to put each one in separated file and hope it could tell me the encoding is different, but both show me as `UTF-8 Unicode text`

My question is how this happen and how to convert the 6 bytes one to 3 bytes one.

Comment: It looks like the second is in decomposed form (see my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them)), but I'm not sure how to convert it to precomposed form.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for point me to the right direction. I actually saw your answer before, but I skipped the popcorn bc I thought ボ is not an accent character. The answer under the same question seems do the converting just fine. 
`printf '\xe3\x83\x9b\xe3\x82\x99' | iconv -f UTF8-MAC -t UTF8  | hexdump ` gives me
`0000000 e3 83 9c                                       
0000003`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

The shorter version is the canonical composed form consisting of a single Unicode code point encoded in UTF-8.  Python example:

```py
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> bytes.fromhex('e3 83 9c').decode('utf8')
'ボ'
>>> ud.name(bytes.fromhex('e3 83 9c').decode('utf8'))
'KATAKANA LETTER BO'
```

The longer version is canonical decomposed form consisting of a letter and a combining mark:

```py
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s=bytes.fromhex('e3 83 9b e3 82 99 ').decode('utf8')
>>> s
'ボ'
>>> ud.name(s[0])
'KATAKANA LETTER HO'
>>> ud.name(s[1])
'COMBINING KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK'
```

In Python, you can convert between the two forms with:

```py
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.normalize('NFD','ボ').encode('utf8').hex(sep=' ')
'e3 83 9b e3 82 99'
>>> ud.normalize('NFC','ボ').encode('utf8').hex(sep=' ')
'e3 83 9c'
```